# PYTHONPATH defined on multiple vs single line in fish shell

Tags: python, path, fish

I noticed that

```
set -xg PYTHONPATH "/path/to/dir1"
set -xg PYTHONPATH $PYTHONPATH "/path/to/dir2"
```

works, whereas

```
set -xg PYTHONPATH "/path/to/dir1 /path/to/dir2"
```

does not work, even though both methods seemingly produce the same value of PYTHONPATH:

```
>>> echo $PYTHONPATH
/path/to/dir1 /path/to/dir2
>>>
```

So if the "visible" value of PYTHONPATH is the same, what is the actual difference that exists under the hood?

Answer (score 2):

When you add to PYTHONPATHS on two lines, `set` is handling it & it knows that there are two Items : this will work.

When you add to PYTHONPATHS on one line, you have included a space, `set` is handling it but it will not alter the given single Item & you end up with one Item having a space : not going to work.

All variables in `fish` are lists : "Multi-line" way gives you 1 variable with 2 items in the list while the "Single-line" way gives you 1 variable with 1 item in the list where this 1 item has a space.

When `echo` comes along : In one case, it shows a space between the "Multiple Items", & In the other case, it shows the space in the "Single Item" : All this is normal.

Comment: You can confirm this Answer by **`echo $PYTHONPATH[1]`** in both Cases & Checking the output !

Comment: `set -S PYTHONPATH` is better to inspect the contents of a variable.